# do while with string and tow statement promblems

Tags: java

```
   double urWallet, prOfItems;
   double sum=0;
   String nmOfItems;
    System.out.print("How much money do you have? ");
   urWallet = m105.nextDouble();
   System.out.println("Pleas, insert the name of the items in the invoice(in one word): ");
  System.out.println("Enter word \"stop\"as the name of product to finish your input:");
      while( !nmOfItems.equals("stop"));
 {
  nmOfItems = m105.next();
        prOfItems = m105.nextDouble();
     sum = (double)sum + prOfItems;
  }
        if (sum > urWallet)
{ 
          System.out.println("You don't have much money");
    }
else   
   System.out.println("You have much money");
    System.out.printf("%s is the item with the minimum price (wich is %.3f SAR) \n ",nmOfItems , sum);
```

so should be like this?

but it dosen't accept that . It's show that nee to be initialized

what should i do?

Comment: You can put an if condition and then break.

Comment: What's the point of `nmOfItems` other than stopping?

Comment: when the user enter stop the code stop the loop , print the price andsum

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Btw, your last edit made the question much more difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @yogidilip

```
 do{  
 nmOfItems = m105.next();  
 if(nmOfItems.equals("stop")) {
    break;
 }         
 prOfItems = m105.nextDouble();     
 sum = (double)sum + prOfItems; 
 }   
 while(true);
```

Comment: it's worked thank you

Comment: could you please explain the steps that      while(true);  i havne't use it before

Comment: if this answer helps you then you should accept it

Comment: `while` or `do while` always accept `boolean` expression. Loop will continue executing until unless condition gets `false` so here I wrote `while(true)` meant this loop always true and continue executing but when user will write stop `if` condition will be true and `break` will exit the loop flow

Comment: if i want to print the minimum price  that the user has been entered

Answer (score 0):

Check the condition right after your action and break out of the loop immediately after reading from console.

```
do
{
    nmOfItems = m105.next();  
    if(nmOfItems.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) 
    {
        break;
    }         
   prOfItems = m105.nextDouble();     
  sum = (double)sum + prOfItems; 
}   
while(true);
```

**or**

```
while (true)
{
    nmOfItems = m105.next();
    if(nmOfItems.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) 
    {
        // If user starts the program by error, or user wants to discontinue process
        break;
    }         
   prOfItems = m105.nextDouble();     
  sum = (double)sum + prOfItems; 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just you should use while not do while

Because do while must have at least one iteration and It do before check on while

Your code should be:

```
 nmOfItems = m105.next();
 while( !nmOfItems.equals("stop"))
 {
      prOfItems = m105.nextDouble();     
      sum = (double)sum + prOfItems;  
 }
```

Comment: Read the question more carefully.

Comment: Sorry see the edit.

Comment: Now it's an infinite loop.

Comment: Why infinite loop?

Comment: you are never setting the value of `nmOfItems` to anything inside of the loop, so it will just run forever if it gets inside